# How to uniquely identify a UIImage before saving it to disk?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, unique

Every time the app is used, a new image is created and then needs to be 'saved to disk'. My issue is that I want to be able to load a specific image (that has been previously saved) at any given time. Obviously each image will need a unique name, but how do I manage this? Is there any way to uniquely identify an image? I can't use the imageview.tag method, as the image is taken from the same imageview every time.

My only thought is to randomly generate a value and then append that to the end of the image? Is that practical? Or even safe? You always run the very small chance of having the random variable being produced twice.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: How about file1.png, file2.png, etc.?  Keep the current integer in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you generate a GUID - guaranteed to be unique (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) - for the file name:

```
NSString *name = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
```

then keep a plist on disk with an array with the GUID you have generated and whatever other identifier you're using (timestamp? label?) to  allow you to identify the image when you want to re-show it

Comment: Perfect. Simple yet effective. Exactly what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using GUID could be an option.

But a way to make sure u won't ever get a duplicate would be assigning the name of your image to the actual Date with Year-Mont-Day-hours-minutes-seconds-miliseconds. It just another option.